# In Jenkins Extent reports Screenshots are blank

Tags: jenkins, extentreports

In Jenkins Extent reports Screenshots are blank.But in local the screenshots are visible.
Path we are providing:

Report path:  C:\dev\ws\Seleniumtest\Reports\ExtendReport.html

Screenshot path: "Reports/Screenshots_Fail/"+screenName+"-"+dateFormat.format(date)+".jpg";

But when we open same report from Jenkins via HTML publisher the screenshots are blank. 
Please share any of your views,Thanks in advance.

Comment: You're using a relative path for the screenshots.  Perhaps you need to specify the entire full (absolute) path.

Comment: @Saianil Kumarreddy Were you able to get solution of this problem?? Suggest me

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem, the solution was to store the screenshots in exactly the same directory as the HTML files.

```
Report path: C:\dev\ws\Seleniumtest\Reports\ExtendReport.html
Screenshot path: "Reports/"+screenName+"-"+dateFormat.format(date)+".jpg";
```

Additionally, you might need to change the relative/absolute paths around as Bill Hileman suggested.
Also, when you get the blank screenshot, check the HTML to see if the path is correct.

Comment: I have tried both of your suggestions but in vain. If I check the extent report html source, then images are not loaded with error: "Not allowed to load local resource: file:///C:/Program%20Files/Jenkins/workspace/XXX_Automation/Reports/addTest.png". It's not the content security policy thing. Please note that I have checked the path- It's correct. Suggest me!

Comment: I am also facing same problem, can anyone suggest some solution?